# Attempting to make an expense tracker

Tags: javascript

I have done most of the HTML and CSS, but I am stuck on JavaScript. So I need to link the button with the table and have it display the data in the table, but I am unsure about how to approach it.

I created a function and used the `getElementById()` method but that was all I could do.

```js
function addExpense() {
  var expenses = document.getElementById("data");
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Expense Tracker</h1>
    <h2>ADD NEW ITEM:</h2>
    <form id="data">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="submit" placeholder="Where was the expense made?" />
        <p></p>
        <label>Date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="date" name="dates" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />
        <label>Amount:</label>
        <input type="number" id="Amount" name="Amount" />
        <p></p>
        <button type="button" onclick="addExpense()">Add expense</button>
    </form>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>date</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row">
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: I think that was his assignment in school... but in my experience, DOM in JavaScript can handle this situtation, much better if you learn first about DOM as well as the Higher Order Array Functions

Answer (score 0):

To link the button with the table and display the data in the table, you can follow these steps:

1. Create a JavaScript file named `script.js` and save it in the same
   directory as your HTML file.
2. In the `script.js` file, define the `addExpense` function that will be
   called when the button is clicked. This function will retrieve the
   values from the input fields, create a new row in the table, and
   populate it with the entered data. Here's an example implementation:

```js
function addExpense() {
  // Retrieve input field values
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
  var amount = document.getElementById('Amount').value;

  // Create a new row in the table
  var newRow = document.createElement('tr');

  // Create and populate cells in the new row
  var nameCell = document.createElement('td');
  var dateCell = document.createElement('td');
  var amountCell = document.createElement('td');

  nameCell.textContent = name;
  dateCell.textContent = date;
  amountCell.textContent = amount;

  newRow.appendChild(nameCell);
  newRow.appendChild(dateCell);
  newRow.appendChild(amountCell);

  // Add the new row to the table body
  var tableBody = document.querySelector('table tbody');
  tableBody.appendChild(newRow);

  // Clear input fields
  document.getElementById('name').value = '';
  document.getElementById('date').value = '';
  document.getElementById('Amount').value = '';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Expense Tracker</h1>
    <h2>ADD NEW ITEM:</h2>
    <form id="data">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="submit" placeholder="Where was the expense made?" />
        <p></p>
        <label>Date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="date" name="dates" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />
        <label>Amount:</label>
        <input type="number" id="Amount" name="Amount" />
        <p></p>
        <button type="button" onclick="addExpense()">Add expense</button>
    </form>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>date</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row">
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In your HTML file, make sure to include the JavaScript file by adding the following line before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

With these changes, when the "Add expense" button is clicked, the `addExpense` function will be triggered. It will retrieve the values from the input fields, create a new row in the table, populate it with the entered data, and clear the input fields. The data will be displayed in the table below the input form.

Note: Make sure the `style.css` file is in the same directory as your HTML file, or adjust the `href` attribute in the `<link>` tag accordingly to point to the correct location.

Comment: Done using ChatGPT?

Comment: Well after having a look at the original code and you guys tidying it up. I thought why not use it to provide a working descriptive answer so that it can be simple for the user to understand. @KevinM.Mansour